# When a commenter corrects my question, should I edit my question to correct it, thought it hides the error s/he corrected?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

When I ask a question, I recognize that there may be factual errors in the text of my question -- e.g. incorrect assumptions. I invite corrections and sometimes a commenter provides the correction in a comment.

I would like to edit my question to make it correct, so that subsequent responders see only correct information. I acknowledge the correction in a reply comment to the person who corrected me.

But at that point, the conversation in the comments - correction & acknowledgement -- is something of an orphan -- people viewing the corrected question can no longer see what was corrected.

Is that OK or should I do something differently?

Comment: As long as the post is/becomes clear, you dont need to worry about the comments.

Comment: I like that answer. Can you post as answer instead of just comment & I'll accept it?

Answer (score 8):

Yes you should.

You can flag the comment as being "obsolete" or add your own comment directed at the original commentator indicating you've fixed the issue. However, adding too many comments adds noise to the system to this should only be done in rarely.

Comment: I've always tried to avoid flagging a comment as obsolete, because it seems kind of rude when someone's helped you improve your Q/A. I usually do leave a comment thanking the person and/or telling them I've fixed the problem. I see your point about noise though.

Comment: @Asad That's one of those things that is perfectly acceptable practice within the SE system but may seem rude to an outsider. The system is meant to reduce noise, so that people don't have to look at irrelevant information. That's why we remove "Thanks" from posts and comments, and why comments which are no longer relevant to the current version of a post should be flagged for deletion. The flag isn't saying there was anything wrong about the comment, just that it has served its purpose and now it's time for it to go.

Answer (score 1):

If the edit makes the question clearer/correct, then you should make the necessary changes. The comments are something you do not need to worry about.

If you are concerned then you can add a comment to state that you have made the necessary changes.